# Fieldset legend getting striked when container has translate css

Tags: html, css

I am using a fieldset with bordor top only. The container of fieldset is position absolute and have translate property to align the modal to centre of page.
See https://jsfiddle.net/wb8ddv0w/1/

```
<section class="modal  medium  someclass" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Some heading</legend>
    <p>Some text on the top. Some text on the top Some text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the top</p>
   <section  aria-required="true">
      <label>some more text</label>
   </section>
</fieldset>
</section>
```

But the fieldset legend is getting strike through. What is the issue.

Comment: remove margin-top from fieldset and give padding to .modal

Comment: Fieldset css is generic and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Using fractions of a pixel usually creates problems

Just make the padding-top an integer value and it works ok

```css
fieldset {
      margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 51px;
    padding-top: 25px;   /* changed */
    position: relative;
}
legend {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 0 12px 0 8px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px #111;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 1!important;
    display: block;
}
.modal.someclass {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="modal  medium  someclass" >
<fieldset>
    <legend>Some heading</legend>
        <p>Some text on the top. Some text on the top Some text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the top</p>
<section  aria-required="true">
<label>some more text</label>
</section>
</fieldset>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `{float:left;width:100%}` on `legend` ,
i also removed `margin-top` from `fieldset` but you can keep it if you want.

let me know if this is what you are looking for

```css
fieldset {
      margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
  
    padding-top: 25.5px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
legend {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 0 12px 0 8px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px #111;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 1!important;
    display: block;
}
.modal.someclass {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
p ,label  {  float:left;
    width:100%;}
```

```html
<section class="modal  medium  someclass" >
<fieldset>
    <legend>Some heading</legend>
        <p>Some text on the top. Some text on the top Some text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the topSome text on the top</p>
<section  aria-required="true">
<label>some more text</label>
</section>
</fieldset>
</section>
```

Comment: I need border-top also.

Comment: don't you see the red border at the top ? there is a border. no need to -1